# Plain text in Apache rewriteCond testStr

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following set of Apache rewriteCond/rewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond $1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?id=$1
```

What I want to do is to check whether the keyword in URL is actual file, and that keyword is only the name of the file, without .php extension. For example, if URL is www.example.com/foo/ and the file foo.php exists, then redirect to www.example/index.php?id=foo.

Documentation on rewriteCond says:

> TestString is a string which can contain the following expanded constructs in addition to plain text:

...and then lists those constructs. So, I am using a reference "$1" and add a plain text ".php" to see if pattern matches the actual php file. But it doesn't work. All examples I found use only "expanded constructs", but none use plain text in test stiring. Can it be used at all? How?

Comment: Try replacing `(.+)` with `([^/]*)`. The `[^/]` part is regex for "match not /".

Comment: I don't see how replacing (.+) with ([^/]*) can help in solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide full path to check for existence of the file using `-f`. Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Oh, I simply needed to escape the dot! But of course you are right, I also need to provide full path. Thanks a lot, it works!